# C#: Always Auto-Complete

Tags: c#, autocomplete, textbox

When I implement **auto-complete** in **textbox1** the usual way, I can complete **only one word** before auto-complete stops. For example, I have these items added to the auto-complete list (accessible from designer/GUI):

```cs
{ "print",
"messagebox",
"disassemble",
"virusscan",
"system.securitywarning" }
```

If I type "pr," I get **print** then that's it. How can I make the auto-complete feature continue with every space so that I can do:

- I type **"pr"**
- It auto-completes it as **"print"**
- I press **"space"**
- I type **"system.secur"**
- It auto-completes it as **"system.securitywarning"**

I would really appreciate it if anyone can help :)

Comment: What are you using WinForm, WebForm or ...?

Comment: @MAdeelKhalid In my case, I was using WinForm. However, I don't mind if it's for UWP.